# is their a way to encapsulate a js lib within a js class

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, oop

i want to encapsulate a JavaScript file (notifyjs) within my custom JavaScript class, so it cant get accessed directly from the page
cant get loaded until the class function got an coll/initiated

```
my_class={
    is_login:0,
    user : [],
    notify:include_js(basr_url+"resource/js/notify.min.js"),
}
```

the function's will be called by something like

```
my_class.notify.notify("Access granted", "success");
```

now what would be the include_js function ???? is their a way for it ???

Comment: The above is no class, but an object. What frameworks are you using? How do you load notifyjs?

Comment: The easiest way would be to put everything into a closure and export only "my_class" . Just get notify.js yourself 'by hand' and include it also inside the closure. Loading on-demand in standard JS is only possible using <script> tag or other tricks based on 'eval', which I don't recommend if you don't perfectly know what you'r doing.